# Why does the accuracy of my convolutional neural network increase after removing the fully connected layer before the final softmax layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I have designed convolutional neural network(tf. Keras) which has few parallel convolutional units with different kernal sizes. Then, each output results of that convolution layers are fed into another convolutional units which are in parallel. Then all the outputs are concatenated. Next flattening is done. After that I added fully connected layer and connected to the final softmax layer for multi class classification. I trained it and had good results in validation test.

However I remove the fully connected layer and accuracy was higher than the previous.
Please someone can explain, how does it happen, it will be very helpful.
Thank you for your valuable time.
Parameters as follows.
[image: flow of layers]

Comment: By accuracy, do you mean training or validation?

Comment: Both were increased. And less number of parameters than the previous model which had the fully connected layer?

Answer (score 2):

When you remove a layer, your model will have less chance of over-fitting the training set. Consequently, by making the network shallower, you make your model more robust to unknown examples and the validation accuracy increases.

Since your training accuracy is also increasing, it can be an indication that -

1. Exploding or vanishing gradients. You can try solving this problem using careful `weight initialization`, proper `regularization`, adding `shortcuts`, or `gradient clipping`.
2. You are not training for enough epochs to learn a deeper network. You can try few more epochs.
3. You do not have enough data to train a deeper network.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have used early stopping on validation loss min. I'm using 1D convolutional layers. I had larger dataset, nearly 1,565,976 samples for 2892 classes nearly 100 samples for each class.

Comment: Early stopping reduces variance, but increases bias. So this might be effecting your training accuracy too.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating the dense layer reduces the tendency for over fitting. Therefore your validation loss should improve as long as your model's training accuracy remains high. Alternatively you can add an additional dropout layer. You can also reduce the tendency for over fitting by using regularizers. Documentation for that is [here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/)